# Deleting your own chat room

Tags: support

Is it possible to delete your own chat room? I would like to know if you can or can't. If I can please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Do you want it deleted? I can do that for you.

Comment: im good but thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only moderators can delete chat rooms, so you won't be able to. Mind you, if the room has\had less than 15 messages or fewer than 2 users that posted, it will get deleted automatically if it is inactive for 7 days.